# how to refer a jar(this jar is part of other war file) file in .war manifest.mf file

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a war file, this war contains multiple jar files. Now my requirement is I have another war file which has dependency on jar files of first war. So Could any one help me how to refer the first war's jar files in MANIFEST file of the second war.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can deploy those WARs in an EAR, and put the common resources in the EAR. Then you can update the manifest in each WARto use the resources in the EAR.

Comment: Yes you are right but I can not do that because one war file(web application) is from third party.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, interdependent WAR applications that are not a part of the same EAR, sound like an awful idea. With that said, nothing is preventing you from extracting the common jars into application server's lib directory. But, why wouldn't each application contain it's own dependencies?